How do I load Open Cycle Map to QGIS?
I would like to somehow install or add Open Cycle Map (https://www.opencyclemap.org/) to QGIS as a layer (specifically to look at cycle networks in London) however, I am not sure how to do this.
So far, I have access to Open Street Map Base layer (XYZ tiles) but it does not provide access to any other layers.

Not sure about  Open Cycle Map in particular, but in QGIS you can install a plugin called "QuickMapServices".
After installing the plugin, you can find the QuickMapServices under the "Web" tab from QGIS.
First go to the QuickMapServices' settings, click on "More services" and choose "Get contributed pack".
Under the OSM section of the QuickMapServices icon, you should now be able to add the layer "Waymarked Trails: Cycling".  This will give you an overview of the cycling roads in London and elsewhere.
Please see here for more details regarding specific road types: https://cycling.waymarkedtrails.org/#routelist

You can add a new XYZ source with the URL:
https://b.tile-cyclosm.openstreetmap.fr/cyclosm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
...which gives a cycle-friendly rendering.
OpenCycleMap can be added but needs an API key first:
https://a.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=xxxxxxxxx
There's a free pricing tier:
https://www.thunderforest.com/pricing/
